# Android Studio Rendering Problems without message

Tags: android

I'm an Android Studio user who has recently experienced the Rendering Problem...

Usually when there is a rendering problem, all cases that I searched have messages - type missing, known bug, etc.

However, there was no error message for my case, and it just says, "Rendering Problems."

I tried many things like:

- Converting API Versions
- Rebuild / Refresh
- Invalidating Cashe
- SDK Version Update
- Remaking the XML files
- Restarting the project / Rebooting
- And plenty of not useful solutions

And the following detail is shown below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.reset(Paint_Delegate.java:1238)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.<init>(Paint_Delegate.java:1179)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nInit(Paint_Delegate.java:675)
at android.graphics.Paint.nInit(Paint.java)
at android.graphics.Paint.<init>(Paint.java:457)
at android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable.<init>(ColorDrawable.java:47)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:357)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:262)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:125)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: show your build gradle (app) to see is your library fine? what is you would like to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to see design of my xml files....

Comment: can you post your xml ?

Comment: Sorry, xml files are not on my hand right now... But I can make sure that xml files have no problem because it was okay before several hours ago.